# send data from node to python and print it

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, json

i have been trying to communicate between node and python
i want to send array of object to python, and print that in python, but my code is not working.

```
content=[
{

    "username": "admin",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "roles": "system_admin system_user",
    "locale": "en",
    "delete_at": 0,
    "update_at": 1511335509393,
    "create_at": 1511335500662,
    "auth_service": "",
    "email": "adminuser@cognizant.com",
    "auth_data": "",
    "position": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "id": "pbjds5wmsp8cxr993nmc6ozodh"
},
{

    "username": "chatops",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "roles": "system_user",
    "locale": "en",
    "delete_at": 0,
    "update_at": 1511335743479,
    "create_at": 1511335743393,
    "auth_service": "",
    "email": "chatops@cognizant.com",
    "auth_data": "",
    "position": "",
    "nickname": "",
    "id": "akxdddp5p7fjirxq7whhntq1nr"
}]
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
const express=require('express')

const app=express()

let p = require('python-shell');

app.get('/send',(req,res)=>{


    var options = {
        args:
        [
          content

        ]
      }
      p.PythonShell.run('hello.py', options, function  (err, results)  {


        console.log(results.toString())

      });

})

app.listen('5000')
```

**Python script:**

```
import sys 

import json

details=sys.argv[1]

print (details)
```

Comment: Can you change your javascript file to print error returned from python shell ```p.PythonShell.run('hello.py', options, function  (err, results)  {
if(err)  console.error(err)

        console.log(results.toString())

      });```

Comment: i changed.it goes to else part and prints [object Object]

Comment: Can you try changing  `results.toString()`  to `results` and paste the output

Comment: Output: [ '[object Object]' ]

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the trouble , i think i got the error. Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we cannot pass objects to command line ,
The `python-shell` is calling  `.toString()` method on content object .
Making it `object Object`.

*SOLUTION :*
Change your `options` object to:

```
var options = {
        args:
        [
          JSON.stringify(content)

        ]
      }
```

In python file :

```
parsed = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print (json.dumps(parsed))
```

Comment: while i am sending large array of object to python it gves this error.    Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG ..  could you please help? in the previous case i am sending array size of 2.

Comment: There is a limit to the size of argument, it depends on operating system , usually its around 100s kilobytes

Comment: You should use pipes if the data is too large .https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/